# Sencha touch disable html button not working in ipad

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, html5-canvas

Am using sencha touch 2.2 to develope an ios application. Following code to display some html buttons.

```
<button id="leadconvertyes104" type="button" class="leadconvertyescss" >Yes</button>
```

I want to disable this Yes button. For that am using

```
document.getElementById('leadconvertyes104').disabled= true;
```

Its working perfectly in Chrome. But when i installed it in my IPod, the code is not working. No change in button state.

Is there any other way to disable the button in sencha touch ?

I know how to disable a component in sencha touch, but not sure about disable html button. Please help me to solve this issue.. Thanks in advance